# In IE8, jquery-ui's dialog set the height of its contents to zero. How can I fix this?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jquery UI's dialog widget to render a modal dialog in my web application.  I do this by passing the ID of the desired DOM element into the following function:

```
var setupDialog = function (eltId) {
  $("#" + eltId).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 610,
    minWidth: 610,
    height: 450,
    minHeight: 200,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
  });
};
```

Everything works just fine in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.  However, in IE 8 when the dialog is opened only the `div.ui-dialog-titlebar` is visible -- the `div.ui-dialog-contents` are not.

The problem seems to be that while in the modern browsers, the `div.ui-dialog-contents` has a specific height set in its style, i.e. after opening the dialog, the resulting HTML is:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="invite-friends-dialog"
     style="width: auto; min-height: 198px; height: 448px">...</div>
```

while in IE8 the `height` style attribute is set to zero, and the resulting HTML is:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="invite-friends-dialog"
     style="min-height: 0px; width: auto; height: 0px">...</div>
```

What do I need to do to get the `height` (and `min-height`) style attributes set correctly?

Comment: *(BTW, others have reported different problems with jquery UI's dialog and IE8, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251176/jquery-ui-dialog-and-ie8), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423194/problem-for-opening-jquery-dialog-box-in-ie8), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578112/jquery-tools-overlay-for-modal-dialog-broken-under-ie8) but as far as I can tell the problems there seem to be unrelated.)*

Comment: As pointed out by Ken Browning below, the code I've provided here must not be the source of the problem -- in isolation it works just great...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can not reproduce your problem using IE 8.0.7600.16385IC using the following test page.  I'd be curious to see how you're showing the dialog.  Are you calling the right method: `$(selector).dialog('open');`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var setupDialog = function(eltId) {
                $('<h1>hello world!</h1>').dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 610,
                    minWidth: 610,
                    height: 450,
                    minHeight: 200,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false
                });
            };
            setupDialog();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Re: your question about method -- I'm actually using `$(selector).dialog('open');` http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ doesn't seem to document `dialog('show')`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: OK, so your code totally works in my browser, so the conclusion is that the problem must be tied to something that seems unrelated in the rest of my code.  Alas!

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to call .height(‘auto’) after the dialog is created.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#phoneDataButton').click(function() {
        $('#phoneDataSearchForm').dialog({
           modal:true,
           width: 700,
           close: function() {
               $('#phoneSearchResults').html("");
               location.reload(true);
           }
        }).height('auto')
    })
 })
```

Credit: http://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2011/10/07/ie8-issues-with-jquery-dialog-causes-box-to-have-wrong-height-and-scrollbars/

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to fix this issue was to add this to the config: "autoOpen: false"

Then on document load,

```
if ($('#DIV_BookingDetails')) {
   $('#DIV_BookingDetails').dialog('open');
   $('#DIV_BookingDetails').height(150);
}
```

(eg the config height is 200)

Answer (score 0):

Found this suggestion on the jquery forum, which solves my problem (though admittedly unsatisfying because it doesn't solve the underlying bug).

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-dialog-height-in-ie8-does-not-work

> force-setting the height in the
>   `.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content` class
>   and including `!important`:
>
> ```
> .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
> border: 0; padding: .5em 1em;
> background: none; overflow: auto;
> zoom: 1; height: 300px !important;}
> ```
>
> The caveats: fixed height for all
>   dialogs; resizing no longer works
>   properly.