# JQuery UI dialog box appears only once in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, dialog

I have a submit button that triggers the dialog box to open during form validation. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE8, after it appeared once and I closed it, when I click the button again, only the overlay modal appears, and the dialog box disappears. here's my code:

```
//VALIDATION OF FORM STARTS HERE
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {

    //create the dialog box
    $.fx.speeds._default = 500;
    $( "#dialog-message_er" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "drop",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        //get the count of errorforms
        required_length = error_forms_req.length;
        //get the list of missed required fields
        var reqlist = '';
        for (var i=0; i<required_length; i++) {
           reqlist += '<li>' + error_forms_req[i] + '</li>';
         }

        $('#dialog-message_er ul').append('<li class="req">You have missed the following required fields <ul> ' + reqlist + ' </ul></li>'); 

        $( "#dialog-message_er" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont know...maybe jquery's version? I8 bug? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687042/in-ie8-jquery-uis-dialog-set-the-height-of-its-contents-to-zero-how-can-i-fix

Comment: UPDATE: I got it fixed! I think there is a bug using the jquery ui effect "drop" in hide event of dialog box. I just put it back to the default effect which is "explode" and it worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the question provided by Luccas, you could probably try setting a `height('auto')` for the dialog element:

```
 $( "#dialog-message_er" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "drop",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    }).height('auto');
```

Comment: UPDATE: I got it fixed! I think there is a bug using the jquery ui effect "drop" in hide event of dialog box. I just put it back to the default effect which is "explode"